# Is there an alternative for Media Query "prefers-color-scheme" using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Prefers-color-scheme is great, but I'm afraid i can't guarantee my application will support it in production. Is there an alternative to it? Perhaps by using Javascript ? All I really want is to know beforehand if my application is set to Light Mode or to Dark mode. Thanks in advance

Comment: `i can't guarantee my application will support it` why not?

Comment: Not my application per se, I just can't guarantee its users will be using a recent enough browser version for it not to be a problem, given it's a recent feature